# Stream create two objects from one and process further

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to create two objects based on a single object to stream and process further. How can I achieve this using streams?

The pseudocode could look like this:

```
stream.stream().
    map(p -> new Object(p.getParam1()) <AND> new Object(p.getParam2()) ).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no need to use both `map` and `flatMap`.

`flatMap` by itself will do :

```
stream.stream()
      .flatMap(p -> Stream.of(new Object(p.getParam1()), new Object(p.getParam2())))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```